# Form Validation Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

Using login component on angular2 applicaiton.

Login work fine but allows users to log in with incorrect/no password and gives no error alert when incorrect. 
What form on validation works with subscription services or authentication?

Any possible solutions would be great, thanks :)

**Typescript Component**

```
import { Component,  Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { Credentials } from './credentials';
import { AuthenticatedUser } from './authenticatedUser';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { CapitalizePipe } from './capitalize.pipe';
import { SubscriptionService } from './subscription.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'login.component.css' ]
})

export class LoginComponent { 
    TOKEN_KEY = "loginToken";
    ADMIN_KEY = "adminToken";
    USER_KEY = "userToken";


    public credentials;
    public authenticatedUser: AuthenticatedUser;
    loggedIn = false;

    @Output() notify: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    constructor(private subscriptionService: SubscriptionService, private http: Http, private router: Router) { 
        this.credentials = new Credentials('', '');
        this.authenticatedUser = new AuthenticatedUser('user', null); 
    } 

    submit() {
        let formData = {
            username: this.credentials.name,
            password: this.credentials.password
        };

        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(formData);
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        this.http.post('/auth', bodyString, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            data => localStorage.setItem(this.TOKEN_KEY, data.token),
            error => console.log("Error" + error),
            () => this.checkUser());
            this.loggedIn = true;
            this.notify.emit(this.loggedIn);
    }

    checkUser() {
        let token = localStorage.getItem(this.TOKEN_KEY);
        if(token !== null){
            console.log('Login successful : token stored');
        } else {
            console.log('No token found in local storage'); 
        }

        let headers = new Headers();
        this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

        this.http.get('/user', {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            data => this.authenticatedUser = data,
            error => console.log("Error" + error),
            () => this.assignPriviledge(headers));
    }

    assignPriviledge(headers : any) {
        this.subscriptionService.connectClientToSocket(headers);
        this.subscriptionService.loadBoards(headers); 

        // set current user name
        localStorage.setItem(this.USER_KEY, this.authenticatedUser.username);
        console.log('Username stored');

        setTimeout(() => { 
            this.subscriptionService.waitForMessagesFromSocket();
        }, 3000);

        if(this.authenticatedUser.admin == true){
            localStorage.setItem(this.ADMIN_KEY, "admin");
            console.log('Current user: ' + this.authenticatedUser.username + ' : ADMIN'); 
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem(this.ADMIN_KEY, "user");
            console.log('Current user: ' + this.authenticatedUser.username + ' : USER'); 
            console.log('Redirecting to my-teams');
            this.router.navigate(['my-teams']);//Updated from playerScreen to my-teams
        }
    }

    createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
        let token = localStorage.getItem(this.TOKEN_KEY);
        if(token){
            headers.append('Authorization', token);
        } else {
            console.log('No token found!');
        }
    }

    logout() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

        this.http.get('/userLogout', {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
            error => console.log("Error" + error),
            () => console.log('User logged out'));

        localStorage.removeItem(this.TOKEN_KEY);
        localStorage.removeItem(this.ADMIN_KEY);

        this.authenticatedUser = new AuthenticatedUser('user', null);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login to Nimble</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">             
                <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loginForm="ngForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Your Username" class="form-control" id="name"
                               required
                               [(ngModel)]="credentials.name" name="name"
                               #name="ngModel" >
                        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                          Username is required
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"  required minlength="4">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder = "Enter Your Password" class="form-control" id="password"
                               required
                               [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" name="password"
                               #name="ngModel" >
                        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine || name. minlenght" class="alert alert-danger">
                            Password is Required
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored " (click)="submit(); loginForm.reset()" data-dismiss="modal" routerLink="/home">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could disable the Submit button until the form is valid using code similar to this:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                    <span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                type="submit"
                                [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
                            Save
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```